# Your browser doesn't support direct access to the clipboard. Please use the Ctrl+X/C/V keyboard shortcuts instead

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, sceditor

I'm using **SCEditor** in my yii1 project & using v1.4.1, i can't use copy and past in chrome(Version 78.0.3904.108) , firefox (71.0 (64-bit)). How to enable clipboard past ?

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHqmO.png)

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: @Jaromanda X   How to enable clipboard past ?

Comment: Doesn't the message state that this is not available for your browser?

Comment: it worked before, i think after some new updates it stop working

Comment: it works in internet explorer

Comment: I'm also having the same issue

Comment: *it worked before* - before what?

Comment: before i update to latest version chrome

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, just like many modern browsers as of date, does not allow JavaScript access to the Clipboard without a user interaction (e.g. the keybind for paste, ctrl + v).

This seems to be since Chrome 66.0.3359 (blink 66) released 2018-04-17, with the `Access to the clipboard is now asynchronous` release.

However that date is not verified, I'm unsure about it and this release is only a guess that I'm sceptical to.